# Build Table in Glue Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

Is there a way to create table or update the table in Glue Catalog?

We are using the following DDL to create a table (and database) in Glue Catalog:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS glue_catalog;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS glue_catalog.date
(
   file_dt           date,
   end_dt           date
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  year string, 
  month string
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/prefix1/date'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv', 
  'columnsOrdered'='true', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'delimiter'='|', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'typeOfData'='file');
```

When we need to make an update to the schema (i.e. a datatype). We have to delete the table in Glue Catalog and re-execute the script above because we're using the `create external table if not exists` statement. I'm curious whether there's a way to create a table if it does not exist, but if it does exist, update the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the alter commands in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-columns.html). Although this appears under Athena service, it applies to Glue tables. Athena tables are Glue tables.

Comment: I see. So, essentially I cannot dynamically set up a situation where Glue would create a table if it does not exist or update/add/replace column if the table exists. My options are either of these: 1. drop table, re-run CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS.  2. Run ALTER TABLE table_name REPLACE COLUMNS/ADD COLUMNS.